# Mass retag: windows home server

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

It was pointed out that we have three tags for this particular product, [whs](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/whs) (26), [windows-home-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-home-server) (8), and [windowshomeserver](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windowshomeserver) (40). Considering how all the other Windows products are tagged, `windows-home-server` is probably the one to keep. Unfortunately, it has the least questions of them. Do we want to:

- Go through and do a manual mass re-tag onto one tag
- Keep `windowshomeserver` as the tag for that and make the other two synonyms
- Something else

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To keep consistent tagging I would really like to see a retag to `windows-home-server`.  Then create the synonyms to point at `windows-home-server`.  I am not certain, but I believe the moderators can do retag everything in a single step.  If their is enough agreement here, perhaps one with do this for us?

Comment: +1 for following the windows dash *something* convention.

Comment: Yep, we can mass tag.  I lean toward consistent tags, so I'd go with the hypens, too.  But I'll hold off a bit to make sure there are no brilliant arguments for keeping a different tag.

Comment: Did it this way. This is the answer to accept IMO.

Answer (score 3):

I've added the synonyms to windowshomeserver, since that was the easy one.  Get voting if you agree :)

Comment: Thanks!  Synonyms are my favorite feature since the upvote.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most consistent tag (compared to all other Windows tags) is `windows-home-server`.

So, I've chosen `windows-home-server` as master tag and added `whs` and `windowshomeserver` as synonyms. I also merged existing tags.